# Install Mesa? How?

Tags: drivers, ati, mesa

I want to try to install the mesa driver to see if it helps my FPS with radeon gpu for Dota 2.

However, I can't find a proper way to install it.

How would I go about it? I tried adding the ppa and running `sudo apt-get install mesa`, but it cannot locate the package.

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Mesa is already installed in Ubuntu. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: If you have Ubuntu, then mesa is preinstalled, and you are welcome to varify that with `dpkg -l | grep mesa`.

Comment: Output is: `[Radeon HD 7950/8950 OEM / R9 280]
 Subsystem: XFX Pine Group Inc. Device 3221
 Kernel driver in use: radeon
`

Comment: it seems like i have the packages. How do I activate them? Right now my games crash quite frequently, screen goes black.. I need to fix it :/

Comment: You should be installing the AMDs proprietary driver. ...not sure what you mean by 'activate them'. Why do you think you need mesa anyway???

Comment: How do I do that? Will I have to  choose "mesa" under "Additional drivers"? Or what should I pick?

Comment: I answered how to install the drivers. Just do it.

Comment: @Pilot6 Duly noted indeed. :~)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **do not** need to install mesa, but AMD proprietary drivers.

It can be done by running

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

Reboot after the driver is installed.

Comment: How do I activate them? Will mesa appear in"Additional Drivers"?

Comment: Just run that command and reboot. You do not need mesa. Why are you asking about it?

Comment: Okay, but what driver should I pick under additional drivers? Right now, i'm on the open source one.

Comment: After you run this command the correct driver will be picked for you.

Comment: Sigh, my fps is terrible with this driver too.. Nothing frickin works with AMD. The only driver which provides me half-decent fps(the open source one) also crashes my system. Ffs.

Comment: Dota does not work well in Ubuntu. But this driver is the best one.

Comment: The open source driver works for me. I have stable 60 fps. But it frequently crashes my entire system(screen goes completely black), so it's  not really usable..

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to install mesa software.
The mesa **libraries** are already installed.
They do come preinstalled with ubuntu.
The **radeon** drivers most work properly.

Comment: So there's no other drivers I can attempt to try in order to increase my fps?

Comment: @cbll - You can try if AMD Catalyst drivers (see answer from @Pilot6) bring some improvement but check your GPU before whether it is supported !

Comment: It is supported.

Comment: @cl-netbox: how did you block-format your post so nicely? It looks like poetry.

Comment: @BogdanWilli - That happenened more or less by accident - the number of signs simply seem to fit. Anyway, if you like it - you have the chance to upvote ! :)

Comment: well then, upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Mesa packages can be obtained from Ubuntu repositories, so it's not necessary to install them.

To check for the latest version of MESA 3D GL available, just go to http://www.mesa3d.org/

From their website:

> **Precompiled Libraries**
>   In general, precompiled Mesa libraries are not available.
>   However, some Linux distros (such as Ubuntu) seem to closely track Mesa and often have the latest Mesa release available as an update.

But, you can always check your Mesa version with:
`$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"`

and optionally download and compile it, but it's not always necessary.